# Conditional Draggable jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contenteditable div for use as a rich text editor. Usually, the div should be draggable. But when the div is focused, I need to turn off the draggable function so I can select text by clicking and dragging.

So, I'm trying to use an if statement like so

```
if (!$('.elemText').is(':focus')) {
    $('.elemContainer').draggable();
};
```

This is not taking effect though, when I focus the contenteditable div.

Similarly, if I reverse it so the div is only draggable when focused. This doesn't take effect either.

```
if ($('.elemText').is(':focus')) {
    $('.elemContainer').draggable();
};
```

I'm also using some other javascript for handling focus and blur events.

```
$('.elemText').on({
    focus: function() {
        if (!$(this).data('disabled')) this.blur()
    },
    dblclick: function() {
        $(this).data('disabled', true);
        this.focus()
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).data('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the Draggable function every time you're focusing or blurring on the element. I have updated your [JSFiddle as can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/2/):

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.elemContainer').draggable(); 
});

```
$(".elemText").on({
    focus: function() {
        $('.elemContainer').draggable("destroy");
        if (!$(this).data('disabled')) 
            this.blur();
    }, dblclick: function() {
        $(this).data('disabled', true);
        this.focus()
    }, blur: function() {
        $('.elemContainer').draggable();
        $(this).data('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Every time you take focus out of the textbox, the item is being made `draggable`, and when you focus on it, the `.draggable("destroy");` removes the dragging feature.

Comment: Thanks mate. Related bug: if the div is focused on page load, it's draggable, though it shouldn't be. Any way around that? I updated the Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/8/

Comment: This is not the solution. Its still buggy cause the div is not editable. Layalar dont you get the problem right? PLease dont wast our time ;) The real sosultion is to allow eventPropagation on draggable. To destroy the hole dragable element is not the best way. Just "disable" the draggable for a moment is the clean solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/10/

Comment: That looks like a cleaner solution. It's still buggy when I set the div to focused on page load though. I've updated the fiddle showing the bug. http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/11/ Any ideas?

Comment: Yes yes yes, take a look at my last Post. Get along with event.startPropagation :)

Comment: Hey m8, i made it work without event delagation. Btw. delegation is an other nice solution here. Check out my post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`destroy`** method.

> This method removes the draggable functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

So you can do it like this : **[`jsFiddle LIVE DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/3/)**

```
$('.elemContainer').draggable();

$('.elemText').on({
    focus: function() {
        if (!$(this).data('disabled')) this.blur();
    },
    dblclick: function() {
        $('.elemContainer').draggable('destroy');       
        $(this).data('disabled', true);
        this.focus();
    },
    blur: function() {
         $('.elemContainer').draggable(); 
        $(this).data('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

For more info read the [`API Documentation`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Answer (score 1):

**DONT use destroy!** Get on with event.Propagation due to draggable or other events. If you guy enable event propgation on draggable for the given "editable"-div this solution will work fine. without destroying anything! The Problem is about draggable... draggable will prevent your click focus event in your editable div ... thats why its not working. Btw... you just need that smart code:

```
$('.elemContainer').draggable();

$('.elemText').on({
    click: function() {
       $(this).focus();
    },
    focus: function() {
        $('.elemContainer').draggable({ disabled: true });
    },
    blur: function() {
        $('.elemContainer').draggable({ disabled: false });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jdT6/14/